# Hovertool callback source selection for multi-plot graph

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I currently use bokeh version 0.12.2. I am plotting a graph with two series of circles.

```
graph1 = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=800)
graph1.circle('fpr1', 'tpr1', color='red', source=source)
graph1.circle('fpr2', 'tpr2', color='blue', source=source)
```

Now, I would like to add a HoverTool which is done with :

```
code = "source.set('selected', cb_data['index']);"
callback = CustomJS(args={'source': source}, code=code)
hover1 = HoverTool(
        tooltips=[
            ....
        ],
        callback=callback,
    )
graph1.add_tools(hover1)
```

The behavior of this code is that when I put mouse cursor hover a red circle, the callback is called and the tooltip is displayed. However, when I hover a blue circle, the tooltip is displayed but the callback is not called. How to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is a [known bug](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2136). There is a ["WIP" PR to fix it](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/5158) but it will not go in this weeks `0.12.3` release. It should be in `0.12.4`, though.

Comment: Great, thanks @bigreddot. I'll wait as it is not crucial for me. By the way, is there a way to debug a callback script ?

Comment: In a `CustomJS` callback, you can just add a line that says `debugger` and then the if you run with un-minified BokehJS (easiest way, set env var `BOKEH_MINIFIED=no` then your browser will stop at that line in the JS debugger console.